# finding the most frequent item using bigmemory techniques and parallel computing?

Tags: r, csv

How can I find which months have the most frequent delays without using regression? The following `csv` is a sample of a 100MB file. I know I should use `bigmemory` techniques but wasn't sure how to approach this. Here months are stored as integers not factor.

```
Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayOfWeek,DepTime,CRSDepTime,ArrTime,CRSArrTime,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,AirTime,ArrDelay,DepDelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,TaxiIn,TaxiOut,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay
2006,1,11,3,743,745,1024,1018,US,343,N657AW,281,273,223,6,-2,ATL,PHX,1587,45,13,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,1053,1053,1313,1318,US,613,N834AW,260,265,214,-5,0,ATL,PHX,1587,27,19,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,1915,1915,2110,2133,US,617,N605AW,235,258,220,-23,0,ATL,PHX,1587,4,11,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,1753,1755,1925,1933,US,300,N312AW,152,158,126,-8,-2,AUS,PHX,872,16,10,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,824,832,1015,1015,US,765,N309AW,171,163,132,0,-8,AUS,PHX,872,27,12,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,627,630,834,832,US,295,N733UW,127,122,108,2,-3,BDL,CLT,644,6,13,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,825,820,1041,1021,US,349,N177UW,136,121,111,20,5,BDL,CLT,644,4,21,0,,0,0,0,20,0,0
2006,1,11,3,942,945,1155,1148,US,356,N404US,133,123,121,7,-3,BDL,CLT,644,4,8,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,1239,1245,1438,1445,US,775,N722UW,119,120,103,-7,-6,BDL,CLT,644,4,12,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,1642,1645,1841,1845,US,1002,N104UW,119,120,105,-4,-3,BDL,CLT,644,4,10,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,1836,1835,NA,2035,US,1103,N425US,NA,120,NA,NA,1,BDL,CLT,644,0,17,0,,1,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,NA,1725,NA,1845,US,69,0,NA,80,NA,NA,NA,BDL,DCA,313,0,0,1,A,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I came close. I think you can do better than this. Which columns indicate delays? Why are some of `df$ArrDelay` negative, for example??

Comment: "I should use bigmemory techniques". More [**homework**](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~gvludwig/327-5/groupwork2) that you want people on SO to do for you? "In the year 200x, which days/months had the most frequent delays?” (Hint: avoid regression". Again, please read [**this**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812) and act accordingly.

Comment: Apparently my question was so broad. I didn't want solution. I wanted a hint. I thought I should use bigmemory techniques not the traditional aggregate methods. I just didn't had the chance to see the downvotes in appropriate time and close the question. Now I can't even delete it! If you look at my question more carefully, then it's fair to judge like how you have done.

Comment: Ohh, I've been around the block with the airline data.  Prepare for many frustrated moments.

Comment: yes, there are many columns which end up causing delay. It's rather hard to analyze especially that the data is very large. They had a statistic competition back in 2009 for dealing with it using parallel computing in R.

Comment: Yep.  A Duncan taught me how to optimize this.  Are you on a linux-based?

Comment: I have access to Linux machine with a large number of cores for doing so and my notebook is running OSX. I wanted to first try stuff on my notebook as it has multiple cores but I am not sure if the commands used in OSX will be all compatible with that of Linux (I think it shouldn't be so far)

Comment: I somehow think there should be another function that can do the parallel version of `aggregate` like how `biglm` does the lm in parallel settings. What do you think?

Comment: If this is a homework assignment for a course you're taking, you should try to get hints/starting points from the instructor for the course, or from your fellow students.  Come back to SO when you have *specific programming questions* ...

Comment: I am waiting for the question to get closed to see less violent comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your data.frame is called `dd`. If you want to see the total number of weather delays for each month across all years you can do

```
delay <- aggregate(WeatherDelay~Month, dd, sum)
delay[order(-delay$WeatherDelay),]
```

Comment: Do we have a `parallel aggregate` in `R`? Like how we have a `parallel for` in some of the programming languages?

Answer (score 1):

Is this closer to what you want?  I don't know R well enough to sum the rows, but this at least aggregates them.  I am learning, too!

```
delays <- read.csv("tmp.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

delay <- aggregate(cbind(ArrDelay, DepDelay, WeatherDelay, NASDelay, SecurityDelay, LateAircraftDelay) ~ Month, delays, sum)
delay
```

It outputs:

```
  Month ArrDelay DepDelay WeatherDelay NASDelay SecurityDelay LateAircraftDelay
1     1       10      -16            0        0             0                 0
2     2      -31       -2            0        0             0                 0
3     3        9       -4            0       20             0                 0
```

Note:  I changed your document a bit to provide some diversity on the Months column:

```
Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayOfWeek,DepTime,CRSDepTime,ArrTime,CRSArrTime,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,AirTime,ArrDelay,DepDelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,TaxiIn,TaxiOut,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay
2006,1,11,3,743,745,1024,1018,US,343,N657AW,281,273,223,6,-2,ATL,PHX,1587,45,13,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,1053,1053,1313,1318,US,613,N834AW,260,265,214,-5,0,ATL,PHX,1587,27,19,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,2,11,3,1915,1915,2110,2133,US,617,N605AW,235,258,220,-23,0,ATL,PHX,1587,4,11,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,2,11,3,1753,1755,1925,1933,US,300,N312AW,152,158,126,-8,-2,AUS,PHX,872,16,10,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,824,832,1015,1015,US,765,N309AW,171,163,132,0,-8,AUS,PHX,872,27,12,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,627,630,834,832,US,295,N733UW,127,122,108,2,-3,BDL,CLT,644,6,13,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,3,11,3,825,820,1041,1021,US,349,N177UW,136,121,111,20,5,BDL,CLT,644,4,21,0,,0,0,0,20,0,0
2006,1,11,3,942,945,1155,1148,US,356,N404US,133,123,121,7,-3,BDL,CLT,644,4,8,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,3,11,3,1239,1245,1438,1445,US,775,N722UW,119,120,103,-7,-6,BDL,CLT,644,4,12,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,3,11,3,1642,1645,1841,1845,US,1002,N104UW,119,120,105,-4,-3,BDL,CLT,644,4,10,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
2006,3,11,3,1836,1835,NA,2035,US,1103,N425US,NA,120,NA,NA,1,BDL,CLT,644,0,17,0,,1,0,0,0,0,0
2006,1,11,3,NA,1725,NA,1845,US,69,0,NA,80,NA,NA,NA,BDL,DCA,313,0,0,1,A,0,0,0,0,0,0
```